# How to delete an AWS Rekognition Custom Label Dataset

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I have created some custom label datasets in AWS Rekognition for testing and experimenting purposes. However it seem that there is no way of deleting them.

So far I have checked the AWS documentation, there is no section for deleting custom label datasets. I also tried to delete the entire project associated with the datasets. And I also tried to delete the s3 bucket which contains the actual image data.

No success so far.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the actual data inside the s3 bucket, it seems like the datasets related to the deleted data are automatically deleted. However the automatic deletion of the datasets takes some time.

I still couldn't find any AWS documentation about the topic.